# What is the quickest way to show that the integral equals zero?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a=x_0<\ldots<x_n=b$ be equidistant sampling points with $n$ being an even number.

How can one show that $$\int_a^b \prod_{k=0}^n(x-x_k) \ \text{d}x=0$$ in a fast way? I showed it by proving that $\prod_{k=0}^n(x-x_k)$ is an odd function w.r.t. $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and then substituting to shift the boundaries of integration. This was quite tedious and I thought maybe there is a quick and smart argument to show it's zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take an arbitrary monic polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n+1$ and consider the $n$-th degree interpolating polynomial $p(x)$ through the $n+1$ points $$(x_0,f(x_0)),\ldots,(x_n,f(x_n)).$$ We have $f^{(n+1)}(x)\equiv (n+1)!$ so by the [interpolation error formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error)
$$f(x)-p(x)=\prod_{k=0}^n(x-x_k).$$ The function $f(x)-p(x)$ has $n+1$ zeros evenly spaced along the interval $[a,b]$. We can take the Newton-Cotes evenly-spaced approximation with those $n+1$ sample points for the integral of this function, which [is exact for polynomials up to degree at least $n+1$.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas#Closed_Newton.E2.80.93Cotes_formulae) But $f-p$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n+1$, and is zero at all sample points, so $$\int_a^b \prod_{k=0}^n(x-x_k)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^b f(x)-p(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=0$$ QED.

Comment: This is kind of a sledgehammer... but a nice sledgehammer. +1

Answer (score 11):

Your way was actually quite smart. Why was it long and tedious? I think after an appropriate choice of notation it's going to sound quite trivial. In any case, your idea is the best approach, that's for sure.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 4):

You can shift by $(a+b)/2$ first. Then the product of the first and last factors is of the form $(x - c)(x + c) = x^2 - c^2$, as is the product of the second and second to last factors, and so on. But in addition, there's one "middle" factor which is just $x$, so the overall product is odd. Since the domain of integration is now from $-(a+b)/2$ to $(a+b)/2$, the integral of this odd function is zero.

Comment: That's exactly what he said he did, isn't it?

Comment: I think you're capable of reading his answer. So no.

Comment: Can you explain how this is different to what the OP did?

Comment: Yeah sure. He didn't shift by $(a + b)/2$ first. Also, he didn't say how he showed the product was symmetric about $(a + b)/2$. Since it's simple the way I described it, I doubt he did it the same way since he complained about it being tedious.

Comment: "I showed it by proving that [it] is an odd function w.r.t. $\frac{a+b}{2}$". Clearly for you, this is very different to 'shifting first' and then showing something is an odd function.

Comment: Odd w.r.t c means showing $f(2c - x) = f(x)$. So here it means showing $f(a + b - x) = f(x)$. And the way I did this isn't tedious. At all. Now go away.

Comment: Have you read the other answers and comments? The top voted answer says that the way the OP answered the question isn't particularly tedious. Did you actually notationally apply a shift to the function and calculate that it was an odd polynomial (which would have been quite tedious) ? Or did you just reason that the factors were symmetric about that point? You said in your last comment 'the way I did this', where 'this' refers to doing what the OP did. I'm genuinely curious as to whether you think your 'method' is mathematically different *in any way* to what the OP did, and if so, how??

Comment: The way I did this isn't tedious. At all. (it's easy to calculate the $c$ that I use). Now go away.

Comment: I'll even write them down for you since you seem to have trouble with them. They are of the form $k(a + b)/n$ where positive integer $k$ ranges from 1 to $n/2$. See, no tedious here. Original poster said tedious. No same. Me disagree with top-voted answer. You see, the OP was doing an unnecessarily difficult calculation, and pointing out how the answer can be obtained easily makes it not identical to what he was doing. The top-voted answer just said it could be done easily but gave no indication how.

Comment: Do you think your 'method' is mathematically different **in any way** to what the OP did?? If so, how?

Comment: My last comment explained this adequately.

Comment: What calculation do you think he was doing?